# iTextsharp with MVC giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, itext

I am using **iTextSharp with Asp.Net MVC** and when i am adding a anchor tag in html table,I am getting this error.

**Error :-**

**Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.**

If I remove this anchor tag then i am not getting this error.

This is my html table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="/Home/Alog">home</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please Help..Thanks..!!!

Comment: That's an error thrown in the context of `HTMLWorker`. `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker. It is no longer supported.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie..so what should i do now...i can't change `HTMLWorker` to `XMLWorker`...????

Comment: From my perspective, I see this as a dead end. Being the original author of iText, I am not responsible for projects that are still depending on versions of iText software that have been declared "end of life" years ago.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie..then there is no way to add a anchor tag in itextsharp pdf's with `HTMLWorker`..???.i just want to add link to my website's home page because the pdf is generated on the fly and the pdf is opening in the same window..so i want to give link inside pdf so that by clicking on that link user redirect to home page...

Comment: If you use iTextSharp, there is a way to add an anchor tag, but you are using Razor... Surely you don't blame iTextSharp for limitations introduced by using Razor?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie..can you please tell how to add a anchor tag with iTextSharp??/

Comment: Read section 2.3.1 in chapter 2 of my book: http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf The book examples are written in Java, but there is a C# port of the examples here: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C02

Answer (score 0):

Better to use "MvcRazorToPdf" 
Please download complete code from, 
https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf